# How to return the last available time of day in MS Project using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-project

I want to be able to return the value (or set as a variable) the end of a given day in MS Project.  For example if the end of the day on 28 Feb 2019 is 5:00pm than i want to be able to return this date/time for use in a further section of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A project can have multiple calendars, so the first step is to determine which calendar you want to interrogate. The [Project Calendar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.project.calendar) (as shown in the Project Information dialog box) can be accessed like this: `ActiveProject.Calendar`. To reference a different calendar, use the [BaseCalendars](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.project.basecalendars) property like this: `ActiveProject.BaseCalendars("Night Shift")`.

To get the end time of a working day for a calendar, it helps to know if there is more than one shift that day. The default is two shifts: 8:00 AM - 12:00 PM and 1:00 PM - 5:00 PM. For example, use the Intermediate Window* to check the end time of the second shift for 28 Feb 2019:

```
? ActiveProject.Calendar.Period(#28 Feb 2019#).Shift2.Finish
5:00 PM
```

* From the VB Editor, do Ctrl+G to bring up the [Intermediate Window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/use-the-immediate-window).

Comment: Great thanks!  is is possible to have it return a value rather than a string?

Comment: Use `CDate` to convert the value to a date (e.g. `CDate("5:00 PM") = 5:00:00 PM`). That can further be converted to a double using `CDbl` (e.g. `CDbl(CDate("5:00 PM")) = 0.708333`).